# How to print all links and select any 3 random URLs in a page in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have to automate a page there are 20 URLs there. I found a solution to get all links and display its name. Now, I have to select and click any 3 random URLs from it. How is it possible?

Comment: Hope random selection is not possible. try once by creating the loop to select the url's from the bunch

Comment: Use the Random java class. Random rand = new Random();

int  n = rand.nextInt(20); If your links are in a list use the random number as an index to access the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture all the links using `findElements` which returns all the links in the `List`.

Then, use `Random` class to get random number from `0` to `mx_no_of_elements_in_the_list`, which can return a number b/w the mentioned boundaries.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.class("link"));

Random r = new Random();
int random_number = r.nextInt(elements.size()); 

System.out.println("random link " + elements.get(random_number));
```

> `nextInt(int bound)` returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator sequence.

Reference:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html